# importing a dmp file into Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, import, impdp

I have a few dmp files (generated by different a user) I need to import into MS SQL. I realize that I first need to import the files into Oracle (I have 11g XE).

My problem is that I can't figure our how to import the files into Oracle. I'm trying the impdp tool, but keep getting the following errors:

```
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
ORA-39034: Table TABLE_DATA:"PO"."PO_VENDORS" does not exist.
ORA-39126: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.UPATE_TD_ROW_IMP [15] 
TABLE_DATA:"PO"."PO_VENDORS"
ORA-31603: object "PO_VENDORS" of type TABLE not found in schema "PO"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 8364
```

Tries with and without remap_tablespace, but not even sure what arguments to provide for remap.

Comment: what were your expdp  & impdp commands?

Comment: I did not create the dump files, so wouldn't know the expdp commands. As for the impdp:

Comment: Sorry, message delivered before I could finish. I used the filedump: filename.dmp argument, nothing special, but can't seem to get pass this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs; looks like you exported the table with parameter `content=data_only` and when you're importing it; Oracle expects the table structure & meta to be present. So either export without the `content=data_only` parameter - or if that's not possible; create the table and reimport.

Comment: Is there any way to use it as is withoutcre-generating the dump file?

Comment: @user1479246 yes - you'll have to precreate the table before importing

Comment: Thanks for that. I've used the SQLFILE command to generate a DDL, which looks like this:

ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10150 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10904 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '25475 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10407 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10851 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '22830 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 192 ';

Does this confirm that the data has been exported with content=data_only?

Comment: @user1479246 there's no way to say from above statements. These are commands for setting up trace files and not DDL statements.